# Counting occurences of chars in string with stream

Tags: java, lambda, java-stream

I'm trying to understand a data flow of streams in Java. My task is to put occurrences of each letter in list of strings

```
List<String> words = Arrays.asList("Welcome", "to", "the", "java", "world");
```

into

```
Map<String, Long>
```

using a one-liner stream.

I know, that in the first place we can stream each word from the list, then I need to separate it into chars, then put each char as key and count its occurrence as value and in the end return the whole map.

It is so complicated to understand. Could someone explain to me how to do it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It could be done as Willis pointed out using the `flatMap` and `groupingBy` collector. But, the expected output type should be `Map<Character, Long>` fo that as in:

```
Map<Character, Long> charFrequency = words.stream() //Stream<String>
        .flatMap(a -> a.chars().mapToObj(c -> (char) c)) // Stream<Character>
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(), Collectors.counting()));
```

Comment: You’re right. Could also do that transformation in the key function.

Comment: This code fails with most characters. Example: `List<String> words = Arrays.asList( "", "Welcome", "to", "the", "java", "world" );` results in: {a=2, c=1, d=1, e=3, h=1, j=1, ?=1, l=2, m=1, o=3, r=1, t=2, v=1, w=1, W=1, ?=1} as seen when [run live on IdeOne.com](https://ideone.com/4s6WDQ).

Comment: You would need `a.codePoints().mapToObj(i -> new StringBuilder().appendCodePoint(i).toString())` or something like that.

Answer (score 2):

The thing you need to know is that `flatMap` is the function that you can use to convert the strings into individual characters. While regular `map` function just converts each stream element into a different element, `flatMap` converts each element into a *stream* of elements, then concatenates those streams together.

The function that converts a `String` into a stream of characters is `String.chars`.

When you want to build a new collection from a stream, you usually use a collector. Using the function `Collectors.groupingBy` you can produce a collector that will create a `Map`, given two functions, one to produce the key for each stream value, and the other to produce the value. There's a variant of this that will let you pass another collector in as the second parameter instead of a function; try `Collectors.counting`.

Answer (score 2):

More readable using `flatMapToInt` than `flatMap(a -> a.chars().mapToObj(c -> (char) c))`

```
words.stream()
            .flatMapToInt(String::chars) //IntStream
            .mapToObj(c -> (char) c)     //Stream<Character>
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(), Collectors.counting()));
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

***In Kotlin:***

```
val str = "Occurrences"
val results: Map<String, Long> =
        stream(str.split("").toTypedArray()).map{n-> n.lowercase()}
            .collect(
                Collectors.groupingBy({ it  },
                    { LinkedHashMap() },
                    Collectors.counting()
                )
            )

Log.w("occurrencesResult",results.toString())
```